# Issue with PHP and advanced regex

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to parse a list of domain names from a bind DNS root zone file. My regex works on regex101.com (https://regex101.com/r/uP3dT7/2) , however when testing with PHP and live data it doesn't find any matches.

Where could be the reason? I thought somewhere in formatting but if it works in regex101.com...

```
$re = "/(^\S+\.(?:eus|tld))\.\s*86400(?!.*?^\1\.\s*86400)/ms"; 
preg_match_all($re, $content, $matches);     
var_dump ($matches);
```

This is my code. Maybe the issue is with the regex or if not, the formatting of the live data.

Comment: Do you see the anchors (`^`) in your expression?

Comment: the regex is definitely different form regex101

Comment: the same regex on regex101 works fine with php https://3v4l.org/rGrfJ

Comment: please review your regex as @Jan said

Answer (score 0):

**Without** the anchors it works pretty well:

```
<?php

$data = <<<DATA
 pblxare.eus.   86400   in  ns  ns1.cdmon.net. pblxare.eus. 86400   in  ns  ns2.cdmon.net. pblxare.eus. 86400   in  ns  ns3.cdmon.net. eginirribarre.eus.   86400   in  ns  alt.guebs.com. eginirribarre.eus.   86400   in ns   alt2.guebs.com. eginirribarre.eus.  86400   in  ns  alt3.guebs.com. n80i564smh8rfmcej1l.eus.    43200   in  nsec3   1   0   12  e5b2f7n ns n8g4vh050i5641l.eus. 43200   in  rrsig   nsec3   10  2 frgrgrht.eus. 86400
DATA;

$regex = "~(\S+\.(?:eus|tld))\.\s*86400(?!.*?\1\.\s*86400)~ms"; 

preg_match_all($regex, $data, $matches);
print_r($matches);

?>
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/qgYYLW).